# Enable esp32 deep sleep mode after a certain period of inactivity

Tags: arduino, sleep, esp32

I have a device designed in esp that contains two buttons, each of which performs a function. However, he is constantly monitoring these buttons and running out of battery. How do I implement esp's deep sleep, after a certain period of inactivity? For example, if the device does not read in 30 seconds, activate sleep mode. To exit the mode, just press any of the existing buttons.

I thought of something from the team, but it’s not working, because the milis() parameter is never reset.

```
void loop() 
{
  unsigned long timer=millis();
    int botaoRfid = digitalRead(butRFID);
    int botaoDig = digitalRead(butDIG);


  if(botaoRfid == HIGH){
    timer=0;
    Serial.println("botao RFID pressionado");
    checkRFID();
    }
   else if(botaoDig == HIGH){
    timer=0;
    Serial.println("botao DIGITAL pressionado");
    checkFingerprint();
    return;
    }
    else if(timer >=10000){
    Serial.println("Sleep…");
    esp_deep_sleep_start();    
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really a problem, that `millis()` is not reset after startup, when you rewrite your code like so:

```c
unsigned long timer = 0;

void setup()
{

}

void loop() 
{
  int botaoRfid = digitalRead(butRFID);
  int botaoDig = digitalRead(butDIG);

  if(botaoRfid == HIGH){
    timer = millis();
    Serial.println("botao RFID pressionado");
    checkRFID();
  }
  else if(botaoDig == HIGH){
    timer = millis();
    Serial.println("botao DIGITAL pressionado");
    checkFingerprint();
    return;
  }
  else if(millis() - timer >= 10000){
    Serial.println("Sleep…");
    esp_deep_sleep_start();    
  }
}
```

This would put the ESP32 into deep sleep after 10 seconds without a reset to the current `millis()` (which is currently happening in every loop cycle, but you can of course put that code outside the loop...). Beware however, that `millis()` will overflow after about 49 days and you will have to handle this correctly.

Also in order to wake the ESP32 from DeepSleep you have to define a PIN to listen on using for example `esp_sleep_enable_ext1_wakeup(bitmask, mode)`. There are also other option outlined [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-external-wake-up-deep-sleep/).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help, but I think it didn't work. That way, the system never went into deep sleep mode and is always waiting for input

Comment: Did you remove the main millis () from the loop?

Comment: What would this main millis() be?

Comment: I edited the answer. If it doesn't help, you should probably get familiar with the basics first...

Comment: I did a test and realized that (millis () - timer) is always greater than 5000

Comment: No it’s not. It depends where you calculated this. If you do it right after timer = millis() it is zero.

Comment: frank, do you know how to set up to wake up esp with the two buttons? I know I have to use ext1, but I'm not able to configure it. I use pins 12 and 32

Comment: I might be able to help you if you post another question with a detailed description of what you tried and what your exact problem is.